# Вывод в файл .c++

Tags: c++, строки, файлы, char

Как вывести в файл значения целочисленных переменных `x`,`y`,`z` (здесь `z` - количество часов, `y` - количество минут, `x` - количество секунд) в формате `hh:mm:ss` так, чтобы если какая-либо переменная была однозначной, слева от нее добавился бы `0`.

Пример:

Для `z=4`, `y=30`, `z=0` должно быть выведено `04:30:00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("%02d:%02d:%02d",x,y,z);

cout << fill('0') << setw(2) << x << ":" 
                  << setw(2) << y << ":" 
                  << setw(2) << z << endl;
```

Выбирайте :)

```
FILE* file; .....
fprintf(file,"%02d:%02d:%02d",x,y,z);

ofstream file.....    
file << fill('0') << setw(2) << x << ":" 
                  << setw(2) << y << ":" 
                  << setw(2) << z << endl;
```

Comment: В файл так не получится записать

Comment: ???!!!! Почему???

Comment: Я про первый комментарий. Сейчас все сработало , спасибо

Comment: Извините, но неужели из `printf` не вытекает `fprintf`? А если вам теперь понадобится в строку записать, а не в файл - вы заново будете спрашивать, а не возьмете `sprintf`?...

Comment: кстати, можно попробовать также freopen - довольно удобная вещь